# Python: auto-join from main thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm looking at a code similar to this simplified example:

```py
import time
import threading

class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.run_bar = True
    
    def entry(self):
        t_bar = threading.Thread(target=self.bar, name="bar")
        t_bar.start()

        if t_bar.is_alive():
            self.run_bar = False

    def bar(self):
        while self.run_bar:
            print("1")
            time.sleep(2)
            print("2")
            print("3")

f = foo()
f.entry()
print("Entry finished")
```

Now, I would assume that when `entry` is done and the main thread reaches the end, the `t_bar` thread will get stopped along with it, and output will be something like:

```
1
Entry finished
```

However, it is *consistently*:

```
1
Entry finished
2
3
```

Is this because `bar` references a member of `foo` and so it auto-joins it and doesn't just stop the main thread to not garbage collect `f`?

Comment: Why should it stop before finishing the `while` loop iteration?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I am getting it 100% but the code block in the `while` loop will be executed at least once with how you have written it.

The first time it enters the check `self.run_bar` is `True` so it will run for all the lines of code within it.

Assume that your `bar` method will be like this,

```py
def bar(self):
    i = 1
    while self.run_bar:
        print(i)
        time.sleep(2)
        i += 1
```

This will produce:

```
1
Entry finished
```

And then it will exit.